# "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0." couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

I was trying get data from view. The code must return one element, but instead, is returning this error:

```
  "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

The c# code that make the query is the following:

```
using(var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket()) 
{
      var query = bucket.CreateQuery("queries", "ById", false);
      var result = bucket.Query<dynamic>(query);
}
```

And the view is this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.id === "P_01") {
    emit([doc], null);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you run the same view query directly on the REST api and see what is returned?

Comment: Try emit(meta.id, null); instead of emit([doc], null);

Answer (score 0):

I done the web request directly to the view, and then I realized that the problem was with the proxy configure of my office. The .Net client of couchbase was not returning any information of this problem.

Thanks